# Error shfmt not found

Tags: visual-studio, ubuntu-16.04

When i open visual studio code editor in ubuntu 16.04 it shown below error at the top.

`shfmt not found! run go get -u github.com/mvdan/sh/cmd/shfmt to install`

However i tried to find out solution from his official website but didn't get any solution.

After installing  `golang-go` getting below error.

```
#go get -u github.com/mvdan/sh/cmd/shfmt
```

Output:

```
go/src/github.com/mvdan/sh/cmd/shfmt/main.go:156: undefined: io.SeekStart
```

Answer (score 2):

shfmt is also available on snap store:

```
snap install shfmt
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install [go](https://golang.org/doc/install) first. Once you do then you can run

> go get -u github.com/mvdan/sh/cmd/shfmt

Comment: documentation changed to `go get -u mvdan.cc/sh/cmd/shfmt`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use:

```
curl -sS https://webinstall.dev/shfmt | bash
```

See https://ostechnix.com/how-to-format-shell-programs-using-shfmt-in-linux/.